# Call a function in all API endpoints with decorator?

Tags: python, api, flask, decorator, python-decorators

I was wondering if there was a way to ensure some function was called in all Flask API endpoints without manually calling the function? This is to prevent repetition in making sure the functions get called, and to avoid mistakes of accidentally forgetting to call it. Maybe with a library or decorator?

```
def do_something():
     # does things
     # does more things

@app.route(/route1) Method = [GET]
def my_function():
     do_something()
     return 200

@app.route(/route2) Method = [GET]
def my_other_function():
     do_something()
     return 200
```

So i want

```
def do_something():
     # does things
     # does more things

@do_something_was_called
@app.route(/route1) Method = [GET]
def my_function():
     return 200

@do_something_was_called
@app.route(/route2) Method = [GET]
def my_other_function():
     return 200
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `app.before_request`

From [the doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/)

**before_request(f)**

> Register a function to run before each request.
> For example, this can be used to open a database connection, or to load the logged in user from the session.

example:

```
@app.before_request
def load_user():
    if "user_id" in session:
        g.user = db.session.get(session["user_id"])
```